# Setting alias names within refcursor postgresql

Tags: postgresql, alias, database-cursor

I am converting oracle rest calls to postgres functions. I want to store column values in alias names and store data in a table using alias names. Below is the code.

```
 DECLARE 
 l_cursor_1    REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
testId :=0;
pack_id :=0;
newtestId :=0;
currrunId :=0;

select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP into nowtimestamp;

OPEN l_cursor_1 FOR
select 'copyof_'|| "NAME" AS testname,"DESCRIPTION" AS testdesc,"TARGET_DATE" AS target_date 
from "TEST_TABLE" where "ID"=testId;

fetch l_cursor_1 into  testname, testdesc, target_date;

insert into "TEST_TABLE" ("NAME","DESCRIPTION","TARGET_DATE", "CURR_TIMESTAMP") values 
(name, testdesc, target_date, nowtimestamp);
END;
```

The data is present in table, however while fetching values its returning me null values. What is wrong with this code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with your script is not returning null values, it's not inserting anything because it is not running due to syntax errors.  
In plpgsql you cannot define a variable 'on-the-fly'. All variables must be defined in a declaration section (starting with declare) before being referenced. Thus your variables testid through nowtimestamp do not exist and give an error in the execution section (starts with begin) even though, except for testid, you are not using them.  
Secondly the variables used in the fetch statement also need to be declared. The fact that you aliased them in the select doesn't matter; they are only defined in references to the cursor or a record based on the cursor.  
 Procedurally you will only process a single row as you execute the fetch just once. If your intent is to process a single random row then that's fine. But I assume you want them all also assuming the id is NOT unique as if it were you do not need a cursor. So the fetch needs to be in a loop (or a cursor for statement).  
Finally, as an anonymous block the whole thing must be enclosed by "DO $$ ... $$". Taking all that into account we get:

```
do $$
declare 
 l_cursor_1    refcursor;
 testId    "TEST_TABLE"."ID"%TYPE =0;
 pack_id   integer =0;
 newtestId integer =0;
 currrunId integer =0;

 nowtimestamp  "TEST_TABLE"."CURR_TIMESTAMP"%type = current_timestamp; 

 testname    "TEST_TABLE"."NAME"%type;
 testdesc    "TEST_TABLE"."DESCRIPTION"%type;
 target_date "TEST_TABLE"."TARGET_DATE"%type;

begin
    open l_cursor_1 FOR
        select 'copyof_'|| "NAME" AS testname
             , "DESCRIPTION" AS testdesc
             , "TARGET_DATE" AS target_date 
          from "TEST_TABLE" 
         where "ID"= testId;

    loop 
        fetch l_cursor_1 into  testname, testdesc, target_date;
        exit when not found;

        insert into "TEST_TABLE" ("NAME","DESCRIPTION","TARGET_DATE", "CURR_TIMESTAMP") 
             values (testname, testdesc, target_date, nowtimestamp);
    end loop; 
end; 
$$;
```

I guess I would be remiss if I didn't mention that the whole script is not needed. This can be accomplished (and doing so much better) in a single statement:

```
insert into "TEST_TABLE" ("NAME","DESCRIPTION","TARGET_DATE", "CURR_TIMESTAMP") 
     select "NAME","DESCRIPTION","TARGET_DATE", current_timestamp
       from "TEST_TABLE"
      where "ID" = 0;
```

**Disclaimer**. The script should run, but has not been tested. Therefore syntax errors are possible. If so look first at the double quoting of table and column names. That is something I avoid *if at all possible* and suggest you do the same.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i have missed type declaration. Its working now.